# Nginx / PHP-FPM random post body content in response

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have a problem with my NginX / php-fpm / Laravel stack.
The content of post body randomly appear in the response, producing invalid JSON.
Request example :

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Host: host
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/3.2.1 (Macintosh; OS X/11.2.1) GCDHTTPRequest
Content-Length: 9

test=test
```

The Response :

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date: Tue, 16 Feb 2021 07:46:25 GMT

test=test{"error_message":"The POST method is not supported for this route."}
```

The error is normal (there is no POST route for this uri). But as you can see, the post body appear in the response. (randomly, 1 out of 5 times the request works fine)

It doesn't come from the Laravel stack, I tested it by  setting a var_dump / die on top of the index.php (before Laravel loads) and the same problem happens.

Any insights ?

Thank you.

Ah maybe my NginX config :

```
server {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error;

        root /root/devs/peps/www/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name server_name;
        underscores_in_headers on;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/html/public$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9002;
        }

        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate [path to cert]
    ssl_certificate_key [path to privkey]    
}
```

Comment: are you sure you don't have an echo of the request somewhere?

Comment: I don't think I ever made an echo somewhere in my NginX / php-fpm configs but if there was, how can I find it ?

Comment: it would be somewhere in your laravel setup.

Comment: Well, as I said, I already said that it can not come from Laravel : 
"It doesn't come from the Laravel stack, I tested it by setting a var_dump / die on top of the index.php (before Laravel loads) and the same problem happens."

Comment: Have you tried disabling nginx caching? https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/content-cache/content-caching/

Comment: I'm having the same error! Not Laravel, but all PHP apps has this bug on the server.
My php-fpm if running on Podman container. The same image on another server with different Nginx works fine.
So I suppose it is not fpm problem.

I have nginx/1.19.7 on Centos 8.3.2011

Comment: @Aymarick do you run your app inside Docker/Podman container?

Comment: I've done some experiments, and it is the php-fpm problem. I put it behind node cgi proxy instead of Nginx and got the same problem. I'm using PHP 7.4.15.
And the broken output happens before any code, so I get error trying set any header from PHP.

Comment: I had my php-fpm in a docker container yes.
I resolved my issue by recreating the container and image (thus updating my version of php-fpm)

Comment: @Aymarick which image do you use? I'm using the latest one, but still have the issue :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by disabling nginx caching:

```
location / {

        proxy_no_cache 1;
        proxy_cache_bypass 1;
        
        #.......
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment and solution that you suggested. But, it would be much  nicer if you can give a brief explanation of which parameters that you change and what does that mean. If there are other values that you can assign to the parameter, make sure to also mention and explain them. But all in all, congrats on your first submitted answer!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by passing: fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "auto_prepend_file= \n allow_url_include=Off" ; in the location section on the nginx conf.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        ...
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "auto_prepend_file= \n allow_url_include=Off";
}
```